# theano - print value of TensorVariable

Tags: python, debugging, theano

**How can I print the numerical value of a theano TensorVariable?**
I'm new to theano, so please be patient :)

I have a function where I get `y` as a parameter.
Now I want to debug-print the shape of this `y` to the console.
Using

```
print y.shape
```

results in the console output (i was expecting numbers, i.e. `(2,4,4)`):

```
Shape.0
```

Or how can I print the numerical result of for example the following code (this counts how many values in `y` are bigger than half the maximum):

```
errorCount = T.sum(T.gt(T.abs_(y),T.max(y)/2.0))
```

`errorCount` should be a single number because `T.sum` sums up all the values.
But using

```
print errCount
```

gives me (expected something like `134`):

```
Sum.0
```

Comment: from the docs - [“How do I Print an Intermediate Value in a Function/Method?”](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-print-an-intermediate-value-in-a-function-method)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If y is a theano variable, y.shape will be a theano variable. so it is normal that

```
print y.shape
```

return:

```
Shape.0
```

If you want to evaluate the expression y.shape, you can do:

```
y.shape.eval()
```

if `y.shape` do not input to compute itself(it depend only on shared variable and constant). Otherwise, if `y` depend on the `x` Theano variable you can pass the inputs value like this:

```
y.shape.eval(x=numpy.random.rand(...))
```

this is the same thing for the `sum`. Theano graph are symbolic variable that do not do computation until you compile it with `theano.function` or call `eval()` on them.

**EDIT:** Per the [docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/gof/graph.html#theano.gof.graph.Variable.eval), the syntax in newer versions of theano is

```
y.shape.eval({x: numpy.random.rand(...)})
```

Answer (score 15):

For future readers: the previous answer is quite good. 
But, I found the 'tag.test_value' mechanism more beneficial for debugging purposes (see [theano-debug-faq](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#using-test-values)):

```
from theano import config
from theano import tensor as T
config.compute_test_value = 'raise'
import numpy as np    
#define a variable, and use the 'tag.test_value' option:
x = T.matrix('x')
x.tag.test_value = np.random.randint(100,size=(5,5))

#define how y is dependent on x:
y = x*x

#define how some other value (here 'errorCount') depends on y:
errorCount = T.sum(y)

#print the tag.test_value result for debug purposes!
errorCount.tag.test_value
```

For me, this is much more helpful; e.g.,  checking correct dimensions etc.

Answer (score 2):

print Value of a Tensor Variable.

Do the following:

`print tensor[dimension].eval()` # this will print the content/value at that position in the Tensor

Example, for a 1 d tensor:

```
print tensor[0].eval()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `theano.printing.Print` to add print operator to your computational graph.

Example:

```
import numpy
import theano

x = theano.tensor.dvector('x')

x_printed = theano.printing.Print('this is a very important value')(x)

f = theano.function([x], x * 5)
f_with_print = theano.function([x], x_printed * 5)

#this runs the graph without any printing
assert numpy.all( f([1, 2, 3]) == [5, 10, 15])

#this runs the graph with the message, and value printed
assert numpy.all( f_with_print([1, 2, 3]) == [5, 10, 15])
```

Output:

`this is a very important value __str__ = [ 1.  2.  3.]`

Source: [Theano 1.0 docs: “How do I Print an Intermediate Value in a Function?”](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-print-an-intermediate-value-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

I found @zuuz 's answer is pretty helpful, 
for values,

```
print(your_variable.tag.test_value)
```

for shapes it should be updated as,

```
print(np.shape(your_variable.tag.test_value))
```

Comment: *** AttributeError: 'scratchpad' object has no attribute 'test_value'