# Print output of a Theano network

Tags: python, debugging, neural-network, theano

I am sorry, very newbee question... I trained a neural network with Theano and now I want to see what it outputs for a certain input.

So I can say:

```
test_pred = lasagne.layers.get_output(output_layer, dataset['X_test'])
```

where output_layer is my network.
Now, the last layer happens to be a softmax, so if I say:

```
print "%s" % test_pred
```

I get

```
Softmax.0
```

I see why I get this I think (namely, because the output is a symbolic tensor variable), but I don't see how I can see the actual values.

And just so you know, I did read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445280/theano-print-value-of-tensorvariable) and also the [documentation on printing](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/printing.html) and [FAQ](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-print-an-intermediate-value-in-a-function-method), which I am also not fully grasping, I am afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.eval()` to evaluate the symbolic expression
2. Use [Test Values](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#using-test-values)

Comment: Indeed, if I do  `print "%s" % test_pred.eval()` I see the actual outputs.

Great. Thanks!