# keras custom objective function, getting data in y_pred, y_true?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to write a custom objective function for keras, and I need to manipulate the data in y_true, y_pred to do this.

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    print y_true, y_pred
```

When I print these values, I get:

```
dense_1_target Softmax.0
```

I am expecting, with a batch size of 128 and softmax with two classes, y_true and y_pred to be of shape (128, 2), but this is not the case.

How do I get to the data here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print a tensor's value using the built-in print function. Check [this other question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17445280/36195), and also [Theano's documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-print-an-intermediate-value-in-a-function) (if that's the backend you're using).